# Constructing integration rules

Tags: numerical-methods

Consider the polynomial $L \in P_5$ defined by 
$$L(x)=\frac{d}{dx^3}(1-x^2)^4$$

i. Find the roots $(ξ_i)i=0,...,4$ of $L$ and show that they are distinct and lie in $[−1, 1]$. (Hint: −1, 0, 1 are roots). Construct an integration rule of the form
$Q(f) = \sum_{i=0}^{4}w_if(ξ_i)$ with degree of precision of at least 4.

ii. Show that $L$ is orthogonal on all quadratic polynomials with respect to the
$L^2$ -inner product on $(−1, 1)$ with uniform weight $1$.

---

The roots of  $L(x)$ are $-1,0,1,-\sqrt\frac{3}7,\sqrt\frac{3}7$.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Im having trouble coming up with an integration rule. @TZakrevskiy

Comment: If I use orthogonal polynomials the roots of$L(x)$ will be the interpolation nodes. @TZakrevskiy